# expo app build error - package.json does not exist in /home/expo/workingdir/build/client

Tags: expo, eas

```js
//eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.13.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}

//.gitignore
.expo/
%ProgramData%/
node_modules/
babel.config.json
package-lock.json
```

I'm trying to build the expo project apk for hours but encountering the same error :

```
package.json does not exist in /home/expo/workingdir/build/client
```

I tried using this command :
eas build --platform android

Here is the full error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding

```
  "cli": {
    "requireCommit": true
    ...
  },
```

In you eas.json? It will use git directly to create clone of your project, so if package.json is committed it will also be uploaded to EAS.

for example here is the an eas.json file:

```
{
    "build": {
      "development": {
        "developmentClient": true,
        "distribution": "internal"
      },
      "preview": {
        "distribution": "internal"
      },
      "production": {}
    },
    "cli": {
      "requireCommit": true
    }
  }
```